# Where to drop information, non-question based

Tags: discussion

For months I've been wondering about something I found particular strange. I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917978/comparing-two-arrays-horizontal-vs-vertical) on SO a few months ago about horizontal and vertical arrays.

Both me and the person so kind to answer my question were struggling to find information about the delimiters that make up either horizontal or vertical arrays in Excel formulas. If you are interested you can look up the question.

Recently I've seen more questions about these delimiters. Strangly there is no to little information to be found on these delimiters on international versions of Excel like my own. In Holland it might be a backslash, English version use a semi-colon and in Franse they use a dot.

Finally I've found some relevant information that might help out users of Excel internationally to be able to not just quess their delimiters, but to be able to actually retrieve it through Excel.

Is there a place to post such information on SO? Or is this site just question-based and is there no real way to share this info?

Comment: It's just question based. But if you can form a question such that the answer would be the information you want to provide, that could be useful.

Comment: @KevinB If you can form a question *that meets the site's quality standards for a question*.  Which people tend to struggle with when asking a question they know the answer to.

Comment: So the best way to share information would be to open a question and answer it myself? It souds controversially wrong, but strangely right at the same time.

Comment: @JvdV [There is nothing wrong with that.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :) (As long as it is on-topic of course.)

Comment: It can be difficult to pull off successfully, because as servy said, if you already know the answer... it's hard to tell what information you should provide in the question to make it a complete, well researched question, without including the answer.

Comment: @Ivar, that's the information I was looking for!

Comment: @JvdV 2 things: 1) do be careful, it is **hard** to do properly so you can get bit easily. 2) some curators are still not in line with the idea and may downvote based on the fact it's a self answered Q. But, honestly, I'd say most self answered get downvoted for being low quality.

Comment: @Patrice, thanks. So what you are saying is that this site's own policy is controversial within it's own community? Offcourse I would try to question/answer according to this websites guidelines. But being bit by this website's own curators seems to draw a line for me.

Comment: @JvdV people can vote for whatever reason they want, so it's hard to determine it 100% without voter account, but some people do speak up against self answering as a trick to gain rep. At the end of the day, voting is personal so it's fully within their right.

Comment: "...this site's own policy is controversial within it's own community?" Ah, I see, New contributor to meta ;-)

Comment: @Patrice I think the assertion that anything gets downvoted for reasons other than quality and usefulness is impossible to back up and serves only to confuse matters. Sure people may tend toward paying more attention and being more strict in their evaluation of self-answered questions, but I don't see any evidence to suggest (or support the suggestion) that people actually vote for different reasons on such questions.

Comment: Asking how to retrieve the delimiter from Excel sounds like a reasonable on-topic concept for a question as far as I can tell. The onus is on you to take it from the reasonable on-topic concept state to the reasonable on-topic question state. So long as the question is a reasonable on-topic question, there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @TinyGiant and all others with feedback, I've taken everything into consideration and decided that my workaround wasn't good enough. In fact, I turned it into a honest question I myself can't answer as I decided to ask the community on SO for a more userfriendly and stable approuch than I have been able to retrieve. I guess my initial question, wheather or not I can post/answer my own question still stands.